# Extract dates from a vector of character strings

Tags: r, string, parsing, vector, extract

I have vector with two elements. Each element contains a string of characters
with two sets of dates. I need to extract the latter of these two dates,
and make a new vector or list with them.

```
#webextract vector
webextract <- list("The Employment Situation, December 2006       January  5  \t 8:30 am\r","The Employment Situation, January 2007        \tFeb.  2, 2007\t 8:30 am            \r") 

#This is how the output of webextract looks like:
[[1]]
[1] The Employment Situation, December 2006       January  5  \t 8:30 am\r

[[2]]
[1] The Employment Situation, January 2007        \tFeb.  2, 2007\t 8:30 am            \r
```

`webextract` is the result of web scraping an URL with plain text, that's why it looks like that. What I need to extract is "January  5" and "Feb.  2". I have been experimenting with `grep` and `strsplit` and failed to get anywhere. Have gone through all related SO questions without success. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `gsub('.+\\s{3}(.+\\d+?).*', '\\1', unlist(webextract))` or `stringr::str_extract(unlist(webextract), '(?<=\\s{4})\\w.+?\\d+')`, maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `gsub` after `unlist`ing the 'webextract'

```
gsub("^\\D+\\d+\\s+|(,\\s+\\d+)*\\D+\\d+:.*$", "", unlist(webextract))
#[1] "January  5" "Feb.  2"
```

Comment: Thank you akrun. "^\\D+\\d+\\s+|(,\\s+\\d+)*\\D+\\d+:.*$" represents the pattern, correct?

Comment: @Gracos Yes, it represents the pattern to match and remove from the string. i.e. one or more non-numeric (`\\D+`) followed by numeric(`\\d+`) followed by space (`\\s+`) removes the "The Employment Situation, December 2006       "  or `|` if there are characters `,` followed by space followed by digits in some of the strings, we use zero or more (`*`) followed by nonnumeric (`\\D+`), numeric (`\\d+`) followed by `:` and the rest of the characters until the end (`.*$`).  The `:` is to match the `:` in `8:30`

Comment: how are you getting rid of the "\t" before Feb? Its the only part I don't understand. Many thanks!

Comment: @Gracos the `\\s+` will match those characters.

Comment: Thanks. Thought `\\s+` was only for spaces.

Comment: It matches `\r, \n, \t` etc. For example `gsub("\\s+", "", "\t Sept \n")
[1] "Sept"`